# Overwrite Application Id Outside of Flavors and Build Types

Tags: android, gradle

I have an application with many flavors (`A,B,C`) and two build types (`debug`,`release`)

In the build type `debug` I add a suffix to the application ID like so:

```
debug {
    applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
}
```

This is fine for flavors `A` and `B` but I can't append `.debug` to flavor `C`'s application ID.

I have looked at overriding on the variant like I have for the `versionCode` but no luck.

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def changedVersionCode = variant.versionCode
        variant.
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            if (variant.buildType.name != "debug") {
                output.setVersionCodeOverride(project.ext.versionCode)
                changedVersionCode = project.ext.versionCode
            } 
        }
        changeApkFileName(variant,changedVersionCode)
    }
```

Is it possible to override a variants application ID depending on the flavor. For example my plan was to do something like this:

`variant.buildType.name.replace('.debug','')`

Comment: What does "but no luck" mean? What were your symptoms?

Comment: "You can't append" or "you don't wan to append"??? for C flavor.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to override a variants application ID depending on the flavor

Yes it is possible.

The reason you are not able to see the expected id is:

> Because Gradle applies the build type configuration after the product flavor, the application ID for the "C" build variant will be "`<your-applicaion-id>.debug`".

So if you want it to be different for different flavors then you have to segregate the `applicationIdSuffix` for different flaovors and remove it from `debug {}` as follows:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<your-application-id>"
    }
    productFlavors {
        A {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        B {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        C {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, refer to official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id).