# Gradle Flavour wise change packageName and applicationId

Tags: android, android-build, android-package-managers, android-build-type, android-build-flavors

I have a core product (for example **School core**) Now I need to launch it for 2 school (example **School A** and **School B**). Only different is app icon splash screen. I try to manage this through flavour. As we know to upload to google play store we need different package name, so I got stuck there.

My flavour looks like this -

```
productFlavors {
    main {
        applicationId "net.school.main"
        versionCode 7
        versionName "2.12"
    }
    schoolA {
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.01'
        applicationId 'net.school.schoolA'
    }
    schoolB {
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        applicationId 'net.school.schoolB'
    }
}
```

When I run the flavour **schoolA** it's saying package not found. I am looking for best approach so that in future any new school can be added with minimal changes.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019932/overwrite-application-id-outside-of-flavors-and-build-types/50082742#50082742)

Comment: yes This is just changing appId. I need to change package too

Comment: You cannot change Package name for different flavours.

Comment: what should be the best approach to overcome this kind problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot change Package name for different flavour.

Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as `com.example.myapp`. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. So  you can either redefine the complete applicationId property, or you can append a segment to the default application ID using `applicationIdSuffix` suffice. Refer to [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) for more details.

Comment: I already added the applicationId based on the flavour as you can see. But when I am running the app (Flavour schoolA) it's looking for the net.school.main.SplashScreenActivity but I have added the SplashScreenActivity net.school.schoolA

Comment: Can you update your question with Manifest.xml? If SplashScreenActivity is launcher activity then you have to define it for `main` too

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve the problem?

In my case it works perfectly. try like this

```
buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }

flavorDimensions "main"

productFlavors {
main {
    applicationId "net.school.main"
    versionCode 7
    versionName "2.12"
}
schoolA {
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.01'
    applicationId 'net.school.schoolA'
}
schoolB {
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    applicationId 'net.school.schoolB'
}
}
```

And now you can put app icon to src/scholA/res/ standard folders like drawable or mipmap.
And use Build Variants to make debug or release of each flavor.