# How to Install Apk Development and Production Version in the same phone?

Tags: java, android, apk

I tried to install development apk in to my phone who already has the production version from playstore, but I got an error that said "`existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed`"
I tried to rename the package, but it seems doesn't work. so Is there anyway I can install both of version apk in my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `applicationId` available in your app module's `build.gradle`.

Alternatively you can use `applicationIdSuffix` under your build configuration as follows:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
           ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are dealing with app flavors, and want to change `applicationIdSuffix` as per flavor, you can check my answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019932/overwrite-application-id-outside-of-flavors-and-build-types/50082742#50082742).

Answer (score 2):

android gradle support 'applicationIdSuffix' . you can assign it in your flavor's or buildtype's config .such as :

```
productFlavors {
    dev21 {
        minSdkVersion 21
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
    }
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
    }
}
```